# Erlang one-liners with eval on remote shell

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am trying to have erlang run a small piece of code on a remote machine with a remote shell connection

```
erl $ERL_COOKIE -name ${SHELL_NAME} -remsh ${REMOTE_SHELL} -eval 'io:fwrite("~p",[registered()]), init:stop()'
```

The eval is not executed on the remote system, it's in some local bootstrap instead. I also tried `-run` and `-s`. Is there some way to do this from `erl`?

Comment: Check out the rpc module. Also, if you run "erl" with the name and cookie set and hit Ctrl+G you can launch a remote shell like the one you're looking for (Ctrl+G, r target@node, c)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of [`init`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/init.html) and [erl](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) you will see that the expression for `-eval` is evaluated by `init` in current erlang node and not by a shell. So using `-remsh` to start a shell connected to another node does not affect where `-eval`, or `-run` and `-s`, runs.